# Issue regarding order by CHARINDEX Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my whole script

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (
STATE CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO #TEST
SELECT 'ME' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ME' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ME' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SC' UNION ALL
SELECT 'NY' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SC' UNION ALL
SELECT 'NY' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SC'

SELECT *
FROM #TEST
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(STATE,'SC,NY')
```

I want to display all records start `with SC first` and `second with NY` and then rest come without any order.

When I execute the above sql then first all records come with `ME` which is not in my order by list.

Tell me where I am making the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT *
FROM #TEST
ORDER BY CASE WHEN STATE LIKE 'SC%' THEN 0
              WHEN STATE LIKE 'NY%' THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END
```

Output

```
STATE
-----
SC
SC
SC
NY
NY
ME
ME
ME
```

Answer (score 2):

See here for what CHARINDEX returns when your search pattern is Not found.
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186323.aspx

To avoid dealing with the 0 case, you could use the below.

```
ORDER BY
    CASE LEFT(state, 2)
        WHEN 'SC' THEN 1
        WHEN 'NY' THEN 2
                 ELSE 3
    END
```

This should be easier to write, read and maintain.

It should also use less CPU, though I doubt it will make a *tangible* difference.

Answer (score 1):

[`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181765.aspx)/[`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) with [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is one way to do it . You can also alter your [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186323.aspx) like this to get what you want.The Problem in your case is that in ascending order, no match records are shown first as `0` is returned for such records. You can Reverse for criteria to `'NY,SC'` and do a `DESC` order.

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM #TEST
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(STATE,'NY,SC') DESC,State
```

**Output**

```
SC
SC
SC
NY
NY
ME
ME
ME
```

Comment: thanks. why this query `SELECT *
FROM #TEST
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(STATE,'SC,NY') DESC` return wrong result. it is bit different compared with your query. in your case u write first `NY and then SC` and i just write opposite and then saw giving wrong result. can explain in more detail like what is happening. thanks

Comment: `CHARINDEX` for `SC` in `'SC,NY'` will give `1` and `NY` will give `4`. that is why I changed it to  `'NY,SC'` so SC will give 4 and NY 1. now DESC will give priority to `SC` and then to `NY` and then to any non matching characters.

Comment: And when it finds no match, it returns 0; see the link in my answer.  Also, try adding the CHARINDEX calls (yours and Ughai's) to your SELECT to see what it's returning...

Comment: thanks for reply. this is not clear `CHARINDEX for SC in 'SC,NY' will give 1 and NY will give 4` what u said. tell me a way to see what `CHARINDEX return for SC and NY` thanks